# Hard Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, for-loop, operating-system

I couldn't implement SJF(Shortest Job First) Algorithm.

SJF work like this

If process arrived 0 time it'll work till the next process arrival the algorithm have to check if the arrival (process/processes) which arrived in 1 are shorter than the current remaining time
Example: P0 executed 1 and still 2 to finish, now we have P0,P1,P2,P3,P4 in 1
algorithm will execute the shortest one P3, and after it P0 then P4 then P1 and so on. The problem is I have to save to all processes their start and end time execution, and the waiting time.

This is my latest algorithm. (Some wrong cases occurs)

input data:

```
Process Arrival Burest 
P0      0       3
P1      0       4
P2      0       5
P3      1       1
p4      1       3

for (i = 0; i < proc.Count; i++)
{
    minProcIndex = i;
    for (x = i; x < proc.Count; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < proc.Count; y++)
        {
            if (y == minProcIndex)
                continue;

            if (tempBrust[minProcIndex] - tempArrival[y] > tempBrust[y] 
                && tempBrust[y] != 0)
            {
                tempBrust[minProcIndex] -= tempArrival[y];
               // tempArrival[minProcIndex] += tempArrival[y];
                clock += tempArrival[y];
                //proc[y].start = clock;
                minProcIndex = y;
            }
            else if (y != proc.Count -1)
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (y == 0)
                {
                    proc[minProcIndex].start = 0;
                }
                else if (proc[y].start > 0)
                {
                    proc[y].start = clock;
                }
                else
                proc[minProcIndex].start = clock;

                proc[minProcIndex].end = proc[minProcIndex].brust + clock;
                tempBrust[minProcIndex] = 0;
                clock += proc[minProcIndex].brust;
                if (minProcIndex == proc.Count - 1)
                    minProcIndex = 0;
                else
                minProcIndex++;
                for (int c = 0; c < proc.Count; c++)
                {
                    if (tempArrival[c] < clock)
                        tempArrival[c] = clock - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework. If you would like help, please be more specific. What exactly have you done to try to debug the problem and fix it? What _specific_ problem have you run into, beyond simply not being able to complete the assignment? Please explain precisely what the code you posted does, and how that's different from what you wan it to do. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates all of that.

Comment: Ah this takes me back to my OS class.

Comment: My code it missing a lot things, I can't finish it so it won't help explaining the code cuz you maybe have a better one (better Idea)

Comment: But if you really wanna know it's okay, I've tried to make loops in every loop i'll finish some checks like the shortest job, in the current time, the next loop to check if there's shorter one in the near future, if not it'll finish it over all work

Comment: Firstly, I believe you are trying to implement Shortest Remaining Time, not Shortest Job First. Your code is too complicated, the correct solution can be very simple, so I suspect you are overthinking the problem. I suggest you make slips of paper, one for each process. Then pretend you are the computer and determine how you would complete the task of ordering them. Hint: you will want an eraser so you can change the "burst" value as you work.

Comment: I did a lot of step by step on papers first and that's what I've got, Yes it's called Like this and SJF Preemptive.

Comment: Okay, preemptive SJF, which I know as SRT. Likely you are confused by receiving the entire list of processes up front. When the computer is dealing with the algorithm, it only knows about the items that have already arrived. You should split your thinking between 1) making items arrive at the correct time and 2) dealing only with items that are already here.

Comment: Easy to Say :3 But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easier if you create a class to hold the process information

```
public class ProcessInformation
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Duration { get; private set; }
    public int ArrivalTime { get; private set; }

    public int TimeLeft { get; set; }
    public int? StartTime { get; set; }
    public int? EndTime { get; set; }
    public List<int> InterruptTimes { get; private set; }

    public ProcessInformation(string name, int arrivalTime, int duration)
    {
        Name = name;
        ArrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        Duration = duration;
        TimeLeft = duration;
        InterruptTimes = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Then you can just run the following code

```
var processes = new List<ProcessInformation>
                {
                    new ProcessInformation("P0", 0, 3),
                    new ProcessInformation("P1", 0, 4),
                    new ProcessInformation("P2", 0, 5),
                    new ProcessInformation("P3", 1, 1),
                    new ProcessInformation("P4", 1, 3)
                };

int currentTime = 0;
ProcessInformation currentProcess = null;
while (processes.Any(p => p.TimeLeft > 0))
{
    var shortest =
        processes.Where(p => p.ArrivalTime <= currentTime && p.TimeLeft > 0)
            .OrderBy(p => p.TimeLeft)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (currentProcess != null && currentProcess.TimeLeft > 0 && shortest != currentProcess)
    {
        currentProcess.InterruptTimes.Add(currentTime);
    }

    if (shortest != null)
    {
        if (shortest.StartTime == null) shortest.StartTime = currentTime;
        shortest.TimeLeft--;
        if (shortest.TimeLeft == 0) shortest.EndTime = currentTime + 1;
    }

    currentProcess = shortest;
    currentTime++;
}

foreach (var p in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Process {0} arrived {1} started {2} ended {3} duration {4} wait {5} interrupt times {6}", 
        p.Name, 
        p.ArrivalTime, 
        p.StartTime, 
        p.EndTime, 
        p.Duration, 
        p.EndTime - p.ArrivalTime - p.Duration,
        p.InteruptTimes.Any() ? string.Join(", ", p.InteruptTimes) : "None");
}
```

which outputs the following

> Process P0 arrived 0 started 0 ended 4 duration 3 wait 1 interrupt times 1
>
> Process P1 arrived 0 started 7 ended 11 duration 4 wait 7 interrupt times None
>
> Process P2 arrived 0 started 11 ended 16 duration 5 wait 11 interrupt times None
>
> Process P3 arrived 1 started 1 ended 2 duration 1 wait 0 interrupt times None
>
> Process P4 arrived 1 started 4 ended 7 duration 3 wait 3 interupt times None

Comment: Hey @Juharr Thank you for having time to answer me but I was wonder How can I know the first time when a process get out.
Example the first process: It get out after 1 time unit 0 - 1 cuz there's some other shortest process arrived, You'r code is great and easy I understand it, but what I have to add to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Do you want the process that finished first (in this case P3) or are you asking to also include the times when a process gets interrupted and has to yield the CPU to another process?  The first is just `processes.OrderBy(p => p.EndTime).First();`, while the second would require keeping track of which process was in the CPU during the previous tick.

Comment: Yes exactly I want to know the time when the process gets interrupted the first time only (first interrupt only) don't care about the other interprets

Comment: If it didn't interrupted the time will be the same as the end

Comment: I've updated the answer to include all the interrupts.  You can of course ignore any after the first if you want.  And for the example there's only one interrupt for one process anyway.